# Debugging AccessExclusiveLock in Postgres 9.6

Tags: postgresql

We have an application, backed by Postgres which briefly locked up. The Postgres logs showed a series of AccessExclusiveLock entries for `pg_database`:

```
[13-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 7045 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 1000.123 ms 
[6-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 7132 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 1000.118 ms 
[6-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 8824 still waiting for AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 1000.133 ms 
[14-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 7045 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 39265.319 ms 
[7-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 7132 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 12824.407 ms 
[7-1]  sql_error_code = 00000 LOG:  process 8824 acquired AccessExclusiveLock on object 0 of class 1262 of database 0 after 6362.509 ms
```

1262 here refers to `pg_database`:

```
=> select 1262::regclass;
+-------------+
|  regclass   |
+-------------+
| pg_database |
+-------------+
```

We are running Postgres 9.6.5 on Heroku.

From what I understand, an AEL will be taken for "heavy" operations such as DROP TABLE, TRUNCATE, REINDEX [1]... Our runtime operations consist of a number of stored procedures, each of which insert/update/delete on multiple tables (deletes are rarer). We do not perform any of the operations listed above and in the linked documentation at runtime, and there were no releases/maintenance (by us) running at this time.

I haven't managed to find any documentation giving examples of when this lock could be taken during the "normal operation" outlined above. My questions are:

1. What could have caused the AELs (if I have given enough information to speculate) and are there any best-practices for avoiding them in future?
2. What else could I look at to help debug the cause?

[1]: [Postgres docs - explicit locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/explicit-locking.html)

Comment: were you able to figure out what was causing this? Having the same issue and I've been searching everywhere for a solution.

Comment: same for me ! any clue ?